# Проблема с wsl и git

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, ssh, ssh-key

Недавно решил поставить wsl. Все получилось теперь есть командная строка ubuntu. Но появилась проблема: Когда я ввожу `git push` у меня просит имя и пароль. Так как теперь пароль = ключ, то не удобно вводить его каждый раз. Попробовал все способы которые нашел (через ssh и другие), но все равно после перезагрузки компьютера это не работает. Мне нужно что бы git больше не просил данные от github'а

Comment: А вопрос будет?

Answer (score 0):

Генерируешь себе ключ:
`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -C "KirKirKsd@blabla.ru"`

Потом делаешь `touch ~/.ssh/config`, `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` и вставляешь туда такие строки:

```
Host git.blabla.ru
   Hostname git.blabla.ru
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   Identityfile ~/.ssh/имя_своего_ключа
```

А потом надо добавить ещё этот ключ себе в доверенные в git'е.
А по-моему ещё можно на сайте Гита ключ сделать, и просто его используй, в эту папку кинь и всё на него пропиши. Только после вставки в папку ~/.ssh сделай `sudo chmod 600 имя_ключа`